# Is it possible to use like js or something to load a navbar in HTML? It's hosted through Github Pages, so nothing server side would work

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple .html files, and it's a hassle to go through each one and manually edit each file if I just wanted to add a link to the navbar. I'm using a bootstrap 5 one.
So, I was wondering if it's possible to have JavaScript take care of loading the navbar instead of me going in an editing each individual .html file just so all the navbar have the same content.

I don't know if this is possible, sorry if it's obvious that it's not possible or whatever, I honestly don't know.
If there's any other way to do it, let me know because I'd rather not edit like 10 different pages just because I wanted to add something to a dropdown menu in the navbar.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using a static website generator. Have a look, for example, at [Sergey](https://sergey.cool/) which is specifically used for "including" common site parts such as navigation.

For other options have a look at https://css-tricks.com/the-simplest-ways-to-handle-html-includes/